# How to fix duplicated model name with using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to use a gem which is [ging/mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) in my rails application.
In the gem, "Receipt" class is used in model.
But I already use "Receipt" class in my application.

In this case, model and table name is duplicated.
so what is the best way to fix duplicated model name ?

I think the below:

- Way1: To rename the model/table name in the gem
- Way2: To rename the model/table name in my application

I didn't find any clew to adopt the Way1.

If I adopt the Way2, I will rename table name then rename model name in my whole application. If possible, I'd like to avoid this way because I've already used "Receipt" in many places.

Do I have to adopt the Way2, or are there any other good way to fix duplicated model name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, since they are ActiveRecord classes, they have the same table and they will collide in the namespace of your application.

You can use Modules to avoid the name class collision, or you can update either the gem or your code to use a different name for the class.

If you choose to put your classes within a Module, for the table son the database, you can use [set_table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/set_table_name/class) to use a different name for that class instead of the default one expected by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned, I thought I put my classes within a Module and use set_table_name. but I have to change my class from Receipt to MyApp::Receipt in my whole application. Do I have no choice but to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You have in one gem, a library that calls all the time the class **Foo**, and your own code that call this class as well. There is not a magic way to avoid the class name collision, what you can do, however, is to enclose all your code (or the gem code) within a Module in order to avoid the class name collision. But its still a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to rename it in my application.